# Orthonormaly span of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It is known that Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonals with weight function $h={1\over\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. 
 but, if I want to span them as an Orthonormaly base, do I just normalize it? or do I need to do Gram–Schmidt process and how?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the Gram--Schmidt process; but why don't you take the orthogonal Legendre polynomials (that have $h = 1$)?

Comment: assuming it's a test and this is the question... this is why i wanna do it...